# Is Chromebleed still needed?

Tags: malware, chrome, browser-extensions

I've been running 'Chromebleed' for years now ... is it still needed? The latest advice I've found on various sites is now over 18 months old.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe? *shrugs*

That is likely the best answer I can give. I say this because most responsible admins have taken steps to eliminate the heartbleed vulnerability from their systems.

**So, for the most part if the majority of sites you visit are mainstream, then you are likely going to be fine.**

However there are also those admins who have not patched...for one inexcusable reason or another. And their site continues to be vulnerable.

Now the problem is, without Chromebleed...how would you know if a new site (new to your normal list of urls) which you were visiting was vulnerable or not, before you passed it sensitive information?

Sure it may not matter if you never post anything to random websites you don't want the world knowing.

...but do you only ever just post public information to new secure sites?

Security is all about risk assessment and mitigation, so if the majority of sites on the internet that you visit are known safe, and you're careful about new sites. Then in your case, the need of the tool to detect unknown threats may not be significant enough to you to matter.

On the other hand, if you like to live a little more dangerously...maybe you read the latest hacker news on a hand full of fly by night hacker sites or perhaps you indulge in a few torrents once in a while...

Then you should likely keep using it. The nice thing here is that to continue to use this tool requires a minimal amount of effort for a maximum amount of protection against this issue.

Like I said, this is all about what you consider an acceptable level risk analysis and mitigation.

On that note, it's crazy to think there are still SSLv1 - SSLv3 sites operating on the web today. So it's not so crazy to think you may still find a site afflicted by Heartbleed.

As of 2014 approximately 18.7% of websites checked were using SSLv2, and specifically ***38 sites only supported SSLv2***...just wow.
[TLS Survey: Jan 11 2014](https://jve.linuxwall.info/blog/index.php?post/TLS_Survey)

Answer (score 1):

I'm the developer of [Chromebleed](http://hoyle.io/) and I don't use it anymore, so... probably not!

As the other answer said, most major sites have patched their OpenSSL versions now, so it's really down to your browsing preferences.

Comment: Thanks for weighing in, but it would also be nice if you offered any experience or details on why you don't run it anymore.